# scatter plot with its own ID

Tags: matlab, label, point, scatter-plot

i am trying to plot data labels in a scatterplot.
For example i have vector

```
X=[0,1,2,3,4,2,1,0];
Y=[0,9,2,6,2,1,1,0];
z = 1:size(X,2);
scatter (X,Y)
```

i am using

```
   for A = 1:size(X,2);
   text(X(A),Y(A),z(A));
   end;
```

however MATLAB state that Error using ==> text String argument expected after 2 or 3 numeric arguments

What should i do to add the ID in each pairs of x and y and also how to display the ID that has the same value of X and Y.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Change z(A) to num2str(z(A)), since text() expects it to be a string.

Comment: thanks alot..but how about the value ID that has the same value of X and Y. how to make the ID not attached to each other.

Comment: @dan there is no built in solution for that, you can try to overcome that by identifying these cases and joining them so the new label will be something like [numstr(z(A)) ',' numstr(z(B))].